# How do I select the last row in a table using CSS, but without using nth child as I render to outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am applying styles to parts of a table to then send as an email. However, it seems that Outlook cannot read nth child selectors and so I don't know how to apply the style to the last row in the table.

```js
styles = [
    {'selector': 'tr:nth-child(4)', 'props': jc_props},
]
```

That works. But not when I send an e-mail.

```js
styles = [
    {'selector': 'tr+tr+tr+tr', 'props': jc_props},
]
```

This does not seem to work.

Shown above is what I have tried. Nothing remotely complex seems to pass through outlook when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/
It seems like outlook supports only class selectors...

Comment: would that be like
{'class': 'Total', 'props': jc_props}
?
With Total being the row name?